# Concatenate parts of names separated by comma saved in text file in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I've a `.txt` file with names of employees. Each line ends with a newline.
I need to concatenate the first 3 characters of the first name and the last name to form one name, e.g.,

```
Schmit,Eric
```

should give the output

```
EriSch.
```

There are about 50 lines of names.
How can I use `fgets()` or `getchar()` to do this along with

```
FILE *file = fopen ( "FileName.txt", "r" );
```

I also have a function

```
void ConcatName(char* firstname,char* lastname,char buffer[])
```

that stores the first three characters of `firstname` and `lastname` in `buffer` and prints it out.

Comment: `fgets` and (`strtok` or `strchr`).

Comment: can you please give me an example of using that ? @cad

Comment: Look it up on the Internet. In my and many other's opinion, researching on one's own is an essential skill and the learning effect is certainly greater. Read man pages or just search on Google. And I'm sure there are plenty of examples available here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strtok()` to divide into two strings. So for a given employee you should do

```
char* token = strtok(EmployeeName, ','); 
strcpy(SurName, token);
token = strtok(NULL, delim);
strcpy(FirstName, token);
```

After you just need to use concatenate the first 3 characters each name:

```
strncat(FinalName,FistName,3);
strncat(FinalName,SurName,3);
```

Just make sure to propperly initialize `FirstName`,`SurName` and `FinalName` and put the code inside a loop that reads each line one by one:

```
   while ((read = getline(&EmployeeName, &len, fp)) != -1) {'code'}
```